# Calculating standard errors of means in factorial anova using R

Tags: r, factorial, anova

I am using a 2 x 2 between-subjects ANOVA to compute the main effects of gender (male,female) and self-efficacy (low, high), and the interaction effect between gender and self-efficacy. I want to compute the standard errors of the means.The design is unbalanced.I calculated the adjusted means but I cannot calculate the standard errors.

```
    > anova  <- aov(RT ~Gender*efficacy, data=data)
    > summary(anova, type="III")

                      Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
    Gender            1   14.3  14.289   4.285 0.0399 *
    efficacy          1    2.1   2.053   0.616 0.4337  
    Gender:efficacy   1    0.2   0.167   0.050 0.8231  
    Residuals        173  576.9   3.334                 
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1


    > model.tables(anova, type="means", se=T)
    Design is unbalanced - use se.contrast() for se's
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your comment. I provided an example above.